# Error message - Need help

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors, error

I found this Haptic Headband project on YouTube (link below) and I am trying to verify the code that was given in the instructions with the Arduino IDE. However, I keep getting the message below and am not too sure what I need to do to fix it. I'd appreciate any help I could get to solve this issue.

I have also attached a pdf of the instructions with the code to use for the headband.

PDF: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/haptic-headband.pdf?timestamp=1602887165

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xD7bfBx5D9M&ab_channel=AdafruitIndustries

```
libraries\Adafruit_DRV2605_Library\Adafruit_DRV2605.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Adafruit_DRV2605::Adafruit_DRV2605()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Adafruit_DRV2605::setRealtimeValue(unsigned char)'
sketch\Adafruit_DRV2605.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
libraries\Adafruit_DRV2605_Library\Adafruit_DRV2605.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Adafruit_DRV2605::Adafruit_DRV2605()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Adafruit_DRV2605::useERM()'
sketch\Adafruit_DRV2605.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
libraries\Adafruit_DRV2605_Library\Adafruit_DRV2605.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `Adafruit_DRV2605::Adafruit_DRV2605()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Adafruit_DRV2605::useLRA()'
sketch\Adafruit_DRV2605.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
```

Comment: you asked for help with nonexistent code

Comment: It would help if you could put the code inside the question. Did you install the DRV2605 library correctly?

Answer (score 1):

“Multiple definition” means that you have something defined more than
once. According to the error message, some methods are defined both in
libraries\Adafruit_DRV2605_Library and in your sketch folder.

It looks to me like you are trying to use two copies of the
Adafruit_DRV2605 library. One of them is properly installed as a
library, and the other is within your sketch folder. You don't need two
copies. If the library is properly installed, there is no point in
copying its source files to your sketch folder. Get rid of that extra
copy and try recompiling.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I got it!